# Setting SCORM course progress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scorm

I'm just wondering, is there anyway you can set the course progress in a SCORM file during runtime? Which method should I check?

Answer (score 2):

Progress would be defined based on the learning requirement by the SCO developer. In general, number of objectives (cmi.objectives) met or number of pages visited by the learner.

To store the progress, if SCORM 2004 look for cmi.completion_threshold and cmi.progress_measure. If SCORM 1.2 we can use the generic element cmi.suspend_data.

To display the progress inside the SCO at runtime, script in JS(ECMA) by utilizing the values stored in SCORM elements.

Please refer the RTE docs for more details,

> SCORM 1.2

https://adlnet.gov/projects/scorm-1-2/

SCORM_1_2_pdf.zip
SCORM_1.2_RunTimeEnv.pdf

> SCORM 2004

https://adlnet.gov/projects/scorm-2004-4th-edition/

SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_Doc_Suite.zip
SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_RTE_20090814.pdf
4.2.4.1 Completion Status Evaluation

thanks,