# Quiz answers are not retained on relaunch of Scorm

Tags: scorm1.2

I am using Scorm 1.2. Here I am unable to display the quiz answers given by the user on relaunch of Scorm Package.

Please let me know the process to store quiz results as I am already saving this data in cmi.interactions.

Actually it is happening only in Chrome as the cookie is null while relauching.
Rest all browsers it is working fine.Is there a way to resolve it

Comment: Ok, you are saving the results. Good. Are you reading them back? What are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the hosted LMS supports cmi.interaction elements.  At SCORM 1.2 most of the elements are optional for LMS implementation. Check for below error codes,

Error code, LMSGetLAstError()

> 401 - Not implementation error.
> 205 - Incorrect data type.

Also make sure set cmi.exit to "suspend" to resume with the saved SCORM data on subsequent launch.

Please refer the RTE documents (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17700430/1341062) for more details,

Comment: Actually it is happening only in Chrome as the cookie is null while relauching. Rest all browsers it is working fine.Is there a way to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is getting packed into a cookie? If so, thats not SCORM technically.  But as mentioned prior SCORM 1.2 interactions were optional and may not be supported by the LMS.  Therefore you may be packing them into a cookie?

If it's using SCORM 1.2, you can try my bookmarklet to see what an active session is storing.  http://www.cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM.  I built it for 2004 first but added some base SCORM 1.2 in as well which may help with the transparency.